# Node.js browser response : Connection time out

Tags: javascript, node.js, browser

I wrote a simple web-server progam that runs on my server at x.x.x.x

When I test it locally: `curl http://localhost:port`

It runs ok, but when I use web browser `http://x.x.x.x:port`

The browser response: Connnection time out.

Comment: Are you sure your server is actually listening on your external IP address? Are you behind a firewall or a router?

Answer (score 1):

Hope you have included response.end() in the server response. This signals to the web browser that no further data should be expected and the view is rendered. Else it would continue to wait for data and would eventually time out. Refer the [Node docs](http://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_response_end_data_encoding) for a reference to this requirement.